# jquery cookie for jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

okay here is the code i have so far

```
$(window).load(function() { 

        $("#notify").animate({top: 0}, 200, null);
        //for css positioning prblem
        $("#notify").css("position", "relative");

}); // end window load 

$(document).ready(function(){

    //Hide notify bar
    $('.notify-close').click(function(){
        $("#notify").slideToggle({top: -100}, 300, function() {
            $("#notify").css("position", "absolute");
        });
    });
});
```

how can i make it so that when the user clicks the button with class `.notify-close` that for the next what ever so time limit the notification bar does not show.

Comment: For a second a thought about answering, but then I saw that too.

Comment: @j08691: Where are you seeing that?

Comment: @dystroy: My opinion, but I sure find this all a little sad.

Comment: @minitech I propose I open a discussion on meta on this point, ok ?

Comment: @minitech: Comment #3 was mine as well

Comment: @jsalonen: I know it was. It's much better than comment #2. IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you,

```
$(window).load(function() { 
        if($.cookie("mynotifycookie")=="read") {
            $("#notify").animate({top: 0}, 200, null);
            //for css positioning prblem
            $("#notify").css("position", "relative");
        }
        else {
            $("#notify").css("display", "none");                
        }

}); // end window load 

$(document).ready(function(){

    //Hide notify bar
    $('.notify-close').click(function(){
        $.cookie("mynotifycookie", "read", , { expires: 9999 });
        $("#notify").slideToggle({top: -100}, 300, function() {
            $("#notify").css("position", "absolute");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i just have a quick question how long is expire 9999 last

Comment: can you alter the code so that it appears once a day please. so so say someone clicks the close button that it appears just once a day. please or do i just change the 9999 to just 1